# SQL Server CE and Datetime Select issue (C#)

Tags: c#-4.0, datetime, sql-server-ce

I have a select that uses datetime, from two datetimepickers, in the WHERE clause. The SELECT runs fine, populates a datagrid, no problem, but bizzarely the datetime part of the SELECT is completely ignored and the whole thing returns a recordset as if only "WHERE x_account_id = " + subaccountID were employed:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(Lib.ConnectionString);
string sql = "SELECT x_scaleid, x_weight, x_timestamp FROM x WHERE x_account_id = " + subaccountID
     + " AND (x_timestamp BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) ORDER BY x_timestamp DESC";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@start_date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = dFromFilter.Value.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@end_date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8).Value = dToFilter.Value.Date;
SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Not been able to find anyone with the same issue online, so I'm kind of stuck. Maybe I'm better off trying to convert all the datetimes to int's, and store them that way - always hated working with datetime types.

Before anyone asks, I've tried various versions of the clause, including the use of '<' and '>', as well as different CONVERT variations.

Comment: Did you check by using any profiler like tool to get the query that was received at the DB. May be at times, the dFromFiler or dToFilter may have `DateTime` minvalue or max value.

Comment: I've used SQL Server Compact Tool to run the query directly and both dFromFiler and dToFilter have the widest max and min date ranges available. My own gut feeling is that it's a formatting issue - the DB format for datetime and what C# is sending are somehow different.

Comment: In that case, try to format the datetime as string and use any SQL Server code like 101,103 to format datetime for SQL

Comment: Doing a SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(40), x_timestamp, 101) FROM x returns zero rows oddly enough. Yet I've discovered that I can do a successful date comparison if I first format my params in the form of 'yyyymmdd 00:00:00:000'. This naturally opens up the option of formatting those params in C# before sending them on, but I am loathed to do that.

Comment: Does your 101 format align with the date time values in the column which you are retrieving from. To note, these formatting stuff works only if the existing records format match and if not matched, we get no rows. Hence in the case of pre-existing data with multiple formats, it is very difficult. or a backend format to be done to make all values look in the same format.

Comment: No, doing a simple select returns all datetimes formatted in what appears to correspond with 126 (e.g. 2013-03-04T11:49:11.0000000).

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' the issue, and by 'solved' I mean put in a hack.

I created a new column in the DB, type int, in the x table. As I populate x_timestamp with the current time, derived from the application, I populate this new column with a number constructed out of the date, in the format of 'yyyymmdd'. So when doing any filtering, using dates, I can simply do a numerical comparison using the two dates picked (again converted to similar int formats in the application). Works a treat.

It's not an ideal solution by any stretch, as it duplicates data in the DB, but deadlines are deadlines and if no one else can suggest a better one here, this one may be of help to anyone else with a similar problem in the future.